# Maximum cpu utilization

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

The Site is showing the 504 gate way timeout  error frequently. Because the CPU utilization was reached maximum. We have used AWS RDS, Hibernate, MySQL, Spring MVC, Apache tomcat 8 in our application. Unable to find the reason for maximum CPU utilization. Please help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is very generic in nature and more information would help however for initial debugging you need to figure out following things :

- Figure out process which is taking most CPU. You can easily figure out this using top or htop utility in linux or TaskManager utility in Windows.
- Go to Application debugging module and logs to see if there are any error regarding you code,MYSQL or any other API Call.
- Also figure out if there are any hanging threads or sleeping process and also make sure whether query execution is working fine inside MYSQL(RDS).
- Last, see if the resource allocated is enough to serve the application for the current number of users.